# What payment statuses are possible in PayPal PDT?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm going to use PDT to handle one-off payments made via a Payment Button on my site (PayPal Payments Standard). In fact, I will also use IPN, but the question is about PDT. What values of 'payment_status' variable are allowed in PDT message that PayPal sends us in their response? It seems to me that not all values are possible in PDT messages, and thus not all should be handled in my code.

I did not find any info on 'payment_status' with regard to PDT in PayPal documentation (and in any other places), so I had to come up with my own idea. I decided that these values are legal for PDT:

- Completed
- Processed
- Pending
- Failed

and also may be

- Denied

So, the above 4 (5) statuses I need to handle in my PDT script and no others. I think others:

- Canceled_Reversal
- Expired
- Refunded
- Reversed
- Voided

relate to IPN (not PDT). Is my guessing correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, IPN will notify you asynchronously of certain events like refunds, reversals, holds, etc, so if you are using IPN you may receive those statuses as “updates” on previously completed transactions.

However, PDT variables are sent back only when your integration’s return URL sends a POST against https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr passing “cmd=_notify-synch” along with your PDT token and the transaction ID (“tx”), so you will only receive the status of a successful transaction, which would be “Completed” (if paymentaction=sale) or “Pending” (if paymentaction=authorization/order).

You shouldn’t receive Denied/Failed/Processed payment status either, as these usually refer to MassPay IPNs.